# LinkedList from .txt file (how to read everything but the first value of each line)

Tags: java

My ultimate goal is to create a linked list that compares the number of friends a person has (i.e. in the list below Joe has 4 friends while Kay has 3 (Joe is the most popular). The data for the list is imported from a text file. My question now is how can I read everything but the first string value from the text file?

Right now the text file has the following string data:

```
Joe Sue Meg Ry Luke
Kay Trey Phil George
```

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import java.util.*;

public class Main    {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String[]> list1 = new LinkedList<String[]>();

        // Read the file
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\friendsFile"));
            String names;

            // Keep reading while there is still more data
            while ((names = in.readLine()) != null) {

                // Line by line read & add to array
                String arr[] = names.split(" ");
                String first = arr[0];
                System.out.print("\nFirst name: " + first);    

                if (arr.length > 0)
                    list1.add(arr);

            }

            in.close();
            // Catch exceptions
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("We're sorry, we are unable to find that file: \n" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("We're sorry, we are unable to read that file: \n" + e.getMessage());
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of a `List<String[]>` consider using a `Map<String, String[]>` where the key is the person's name. Or better yet, use Guava's `Multimap<String, String>` which will handle the collection issues for you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to save an array that contains all names except the first, separately for each line in your file, you could replace

```
list1.add(arr);
```

by the following:

```
list1.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note here a file of names where first name last name and middle name are separated by space will be impossible for you to sort. One cannot assume that every name is compose of only first and last name. Maybe I got it wrong by reading your question but you will need more like a CSV file where every name would be separated by a comma then you could use something like:

`String[] array = String.split(",");`

`int numberOfFriend = array.length - 1;`

Comment: I believe each line is set up where the first element is the person, and the rest are the friends (first names only)

Comment: I'm not one to judge cause I was given stupid file to handle and that looks like a stupid one :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Guava:

```
 Iterable<String> elements = Splitter.on(" ").split(line);
 String firstNameInLine = Iterables.getFirst(elements);
 Iterable<String> restOfNamesInLine = Iterables.skip(elements, 1);
```

- [Iterables](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html)
- [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is to call the readLine() one time just before entering your while-loop, and not adding it to the array.